# Google SEO prevent dirty parameters

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt

We are currently using prerender for an anguar site (site.com). But we have a problem.

When we run site:site.com in Google a lot of search-result links show up like this:

```
site.com?ref=adirtyurl.com
```

How can we prevent this from showing up in google?

I've already added this to my robots.txt file, but what if these spammers start to use different parameters? I want to try to restrict this completly

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?ref=*
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some rewrite-rules which returns error 404, except the allowed parameters:

```
    <rule name="BlockUrlParams" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(?!.*\b_escaped_fragment_\b)" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\?" />          
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="File or directory not found." statusDescription="The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." />
    </rule>
```